# How to set the root of the repository to another directory

Tags: github

I am very new to git and I am really not getting this:
I am using the commands listed in the tutorials to add and commit my repository. But I got the whole absolute path in the title:

```
Documents/programming/foo
```

I expected the folder to be equivalent to master. So that all the files in the folder would be directly in the repository.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

To clarify: I want the files in the folder on my computer to be directly on the github page of that project, and not be displayed in that subdirectory they are displayed in.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about? :] There is no such a thing as "master directory". "Master" is a default branch in the git repo, that has nothing to do with file structure.

Comment: I think this is just a quirk of how Github displays empty subdirectories so you don't have to drill down with multiple clicks. Also Git doesn't directly track directories, just the files in them, so that might influence how Github displays your repository. If you add a file in `Documents/` I think it will go away.

Comment: @JiriKremser I want the files in the directory to be directly there on the github page, and not in some subdirectory.

Comment: it only depends on where you create your repo. It looks like you created in the parent dir of Documents.

Comment: You shouldn't have created a directory inside your repository if you didnt want to push them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've created your git repo (running the `$git init`) in a bad directory.

If you are asking how to make your repository "flat", i.e. no sub-directories, just bunch of files in the root directory, here is the answer.

assuming you are in `Documents/programming/foo`

```
$ rm -rf ../../../.git # 0
$ git init # 1
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<your_name>/<your_repo_name> # 2
$ git add -A # 3
$ git commit -m "initial commit 2.0" # 4
$ git push -f origin master # 5

(0) deleting the git metadata from your home directory (trust me, you don't want to make your home directory public on GitHub)
(1) initialize git repo in current working directory (foo)
(2) linking your local repo and the GitHub one by adding a remote
(3) adding all the files to staging area
(4) making a commit
(5) pushing the commit to GitHub
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I want the files in the directory to be directly there on the github page, and not in some subdirectory.*

If you're seeing `Documents/programming/foo` this means you created the repository in your home directory.   I imagine you did something like this...

```
$ cd ~
$ git init
```

A Git repository encompass where you initialize it and everything under that.  At this point your repository is covering your entire home directory.  Probably not what you wanted.

None of your files are in the repository until you add them.  So you probably did something like this...

```
$ cd Documents
$ mkdir programming
$ cd programming
<edit and save foo>
$ git add foo
$ git commit
```

Now `~/Documents/programming/foo` is in the repository.  Once it's pushed to Github that's what you'll see.

---

Instead, you want to create *one Git repository per project*.  So drill down into `~/Documents/programming`, make a directory for your project, and `git init` in there.

```
$ cd ~/Documents/programming
$ mkdir some_project
$ cd some_project
$ git init
<edit and and commit files>
```